# Object Equality in .NET Domain Models

Tags: .net, equality

I'm looking for recommendations on best practices when implementing equality in a domain model.  As I see it, there are three (3) types of equality:

1. Referential Equality - meaning that both objects are stored in the same
                         physical memory space.
2. Identity Equality - meaning that both object have the same identity value.
                      For instance, two Order objects with the same Order Number
                      represent the same entity. This is especially important
                      when storing values in lists, hashtables, etc. and the
                      object needs a unique identity for lookup.
3. Value Equality - both objects have all properties the same.

By convention, .NET provides two (2) ways to test for equality: Equals and ==. So how do we map the three (3) types to the two (2) methods?

I, of course, left out Object.ReferenceEquals which MS added in recognition that most people were overriding Equals because referential equality wasn't their desired behavior. So maybe we can cross off the first type (?).

Given the behavior of GetHashCode and Equals in the context of a hashtable, is it safe to say that Equals should always provide Identity Equality?  If so, how do we provide callers with as way to test for Value Equality?

And, don't most developers assume that Equals and == will yield the same result?  Since == tests referential equality, does this mean we should also be overloading == when we override Equals?

Your thoughts?

**UPDATE**

I don't know all of the details but I was informed (in an in-person conversation with a colleague) that WPF has strict requirements that data-bound objects use referential equality for Equals or data-binding does not work correctly.

Also, looking at typical Assert classes, there is even more confusing semantics. AreEqual(a, b) will typically use the Equals method implying Identity or Value Equality while AreSame(a, b) uses ReferenceEquals for Referential Equality.

Comment: Everything that I have found so far seem to point to WPF using `Equals()` and not `ReferenceEquals()` or `==` to do equality. [Link 1](http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/DataRefreshInWPF.aspx) [Link 2](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2007/03/beware-datacontext-and-equals.html). Might it be that your colleague had changed the `Equals()` method on a class to work one way, changed the data, expected the databinding to update and it did not because `Equals()` still returned true?

Comment: Thanks, I think the opening paragraph of the second link explains it perfectly (and better than my colleague!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I'd propose my summary from the above posts as well as outside conversations as an answer rather than confuse the topic by updating the original post. I'll leave the topic open and let readers vote which answer they feel is the best before selecting one.

Here are the key points that I've gleened from these discussions:

1. Entities by their very definition in domain models have identity.
2. Aggregate Roots are (according to the definitions I've read) entities that contain other entities; therefore, an aggregate also has identity.
3. While entities are mutable, their identity should not be.
4. Microsoft guidelines indicate that that when GetHashCode() for two objects is equal, Equals should return true for those objects.
5. When storing an entity in a hashtable, GetHashCode should return a value that represents the identity of that entity.
6. Identity Equality does not mean Referential Equality or Value Equality. Nor does Value Equality mean Referential Equality.  But, Referential Equality does mean Identity and Value Equality.

Truth be told, what I have come to realize is that this may simply be a syntax/semantics issue. We need a third way of defining equality.  We have two:

**Equals**. In a domain model, two entities are *equal* when they share the same identity. I feel this must be the case in order to satisfy #4 & #5 above.  We use the entity's identity to generate the hashcode returned from GetHashCode, therefore, the same values must be used to determine *equality*.

**Same**.  Based on existing usage (in debugging and testing frameworks), when two object/entities are the same, they reference the same instance (Referential Equality).

**???**. How then do we indicate Value Equality in code?

In all of my conversations I found that we are applying qualifiers to shape these terms one way or another; using names like "IdentityEquals" and "IsSameXYZ" so "Equals" means Value Equality or "IsEquivalentTo" and "ExactlyEquals" to mean Value Equality so "Equals" means Identity Equality.

While I appreciate flexibility, the more I walk down this path the more I realize no two developers see this the same way.  And that causes problems.

And I can tell you that every developer I talked to, to a one, indicated that they expect "==" to behave exactly the same as Equals. Yet, Microsoft recommends not overloading "==" even if we override Equals.  It would have been nice if the core == operator would have simply delegated to Equals.

So, bottom line, I will be overriding Equals to provide Identity Equality, provide a SameAs method for Referential Equality (just a convenience wrapper on ReferenceEquals) and overloading == in our base class to use Equals so they are consistent.  I will then use comparers to "compare" the values of two "equal" entities.

More thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

For referential equality, i use `object.ReferenceEquals` as you said, though you can also just cast the references to objects and compare them (as long as they are reference types).

For 2 and 3 it really depends what the developer wants, if they want to define equality as identity or value equality.  Typically, I like to keep my Equals() as value equality and then provide external comparers for identity equality.

Most methods that compare items give you the ability to pass in a custom comparer, and that is where I typically pass in any custom equality comparer (like identity), but that's me.

And as I said, that's my typical usage, I've also constructed object models where I do only consider a subset of properties to represent identity and the others aren't compared.

You can always create a very simple ProjectionComparer that takes any type and creates a comparer based on a projection, makes it very easy to pass custom comparers for identity, etc at point of need and leave the Equals() method just for value.

Also, typically, I personally don't overload == unless I am writing a value type that needs the typical comparison operators because there's so much confusion with operator overloading and how overloads aren't overrides.

But again, that's just my opinion :-)

**UPDATE** Here's my projection comparer, you can find many other implementations, of course, but this one works well for me, it implements both `EqualityComparer<TCompare>` (supports `bool Equals(T, T)` and `int GetHashCode(T)` and `IComparer<T>` which supports `Compare(T, T)`):

```
public sealed class ProjectionComparer<TCompare, TProjected> : EqualityComparer<TCompare>, IComparer<TCompare>
{
    private readonly Func<TCompare, TProjected> _projection;

            // construct with the projection
    public ProjectionComparer(Func<TCompare, TProjected> projection)
    {
        if (projection == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("projection");
        }

        _projection = projection;
    }

    // Compares objects, if either object is null, use standard null rules
            // for compare, then compare projection of each if both not null.
    public int Compare(TCompare left, TCompare right)
    {
        // if both same object or both null, return zero automatically
        if (ReferenceEquals(left, right))
        {
            return 0;
        }

        // can only happen if left null and right not null
        if (left == null)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        // can only happen if right null and left non-null
        if (right == null)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        // otherwise compare the projections
        return Comparer<TProjected>.Default.Compare(_projection(left), _projection(right));
    }

    // Equals method that checks for null objects and then checks projection
    public override bool Equals(TCompare left, TCompare right)
    {
        // why bother to extract if they refer to same object...
        if (ReferenceEquals(left, right))
        {
            return true;
        }

        // if either is null, no sense checking either (both are null is handled by ReferenceEquals())
        if (left == null || right == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return Equals(_projection(left), _projection(right));
    }

    // GetHashCode method that gets hash code of the projection result
    public override int GetHashCode(TCompare obj)
    {
        // unlike Equals, GetHashCode() should never be called on a null object
        if (obj == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
        }

        var key = _projection(obj);

        // I decided since obj is non-null, i'd return zero if key was null.
        return key == null ? 0 : key.GetHashCode();
    }

    // Factory method to generate the comparer for the projection using type
    public static ProjectionComparer<TCompare, TProjected> Create<TCompare, 
                     TProjected>(Func<TCompare, TProjected> projection)
    {
        return new ProjectionComparer<TCompare, TProjected>(projection);
    }
}
```

This let's you do things like:

```
List<Employee> emp = ...;

// sort by ID
emp.Sort(ProjectionComparer.Create((Employee e) => e.ID));

// sort by name
emp.Sort(ProjectionComparer.Create((Employee e) => e.Name));
```

Comment: So if I follow you, your Equals overrides perform full Value Equality and if you are using a hashtable or dictionary with the object you supply a comparer for the hashtable to perform Identity Equality. Correct?

Comment: @SonOfPirate: Typically.  And that's only IF I need one, if my class is mostly a functionality class (such as a DAO, etc) I generally won't bother.  Only in POCOs does it really become an issue.  It just really depends on what my need is, do I need value or identity equality for the current business case.

Comment: @SonOfPirate: And there's many times I won't override Equals() and will just use a projection comparer because I don't have a need of the class defining equality.

Comment: By "projection comparer" I assume you are referring to a lambda as opposed to an explicit class?

Answer (score 1):

The way I usually develop my domain models is around `==` and `ReferenceEquals()` performing referential equality. And `Equals()` performing value equality. The reason I use none of these for identity equality is three-fold:

**Not everything has an identity**, so would cause confusion about how Equals() and == actually work when an object without identity is involved. Think for example about a cache containing several entities, or temporary /  helper objects. What about aggregated objects which might be based on several different domain objects? Which identity would it compare?

**Identity equality is a subset of value equality**, from my experience whenever identity equality is involved, value equality is not far behind and usually value identity includes identity equality aswell. After all if the identities are not the same, are the values really the same?

**What does identity equality on it's own really say**, ask yourself this question: "What does identity equality mean without context?" Is a user with Id 1 equal to a comment with Id 1? I certainly hope not as both entities are very different things.

So why use any of the build-in equality methods (`==` and `Equals()`) for something that is the exception, and not the rule? Instead I tend to implement a base class which provides my identity information and implement identity equality depending on how common identity equality is within my current domain.

For example; in a domain where identity equality is very uncommon I would create a custom `EqualityComparer<T>` to do identity equality when and where needed in a context sensitive way if identity equality is not a common issue within my current domain.

However, in a domain where identity equality is very common I'd instead opt for a method in my identity base-class called `IdentityEquals()` which takes care of the identity equality on a base-level.

This way I only expose identity equality where it is relevant and logical. Without any potential confusion about how any of my equality checks might work. Whether it be `Equals()`, `==`, or `IdentityEquals` / `EqualityComparer<T>` (depending on how common identity equality is within my domain).

Also as a side note I would recommend reading Microsoft's [guidelines for overloading equality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Specifically:

> By default, the operator == tests for reference equality by
>   determining if two references indicate the same object, so reference
>   types do not need to implement operator == in order to gain this
>   functionality. When a type is immutable, meaning the data contained in
>   the instance cannot be changed, overloading operator == to compare
>   value equality instead of reference equality can be useful because, as
>   immutable objects, they can be considered the same as long as they
>   have the same value. **Overriding operator == in non-immutable types is
>   not recommended.**

**EDIT:**

Regarding `Assert.AreEqual` and `Assert.AreSame`, your domain defines what equality means; whether it be reference, identity or value. So by extension your definition of `Equals` within your domain also extends to the definition of `Assert.AreEqual`. If you say that `Equals` checks for identity equality then by logical extension `Assert.AreEqual` will verify identity equality.

`Assert.AreSame` checks whether both objects are the same object. Same and equals are two different concepts. The only way to check whether object referenced by A is the same as the object referenced by B is referential equality. Semantically and syntactically both names make sense.

Comment: I agree that consistency is desired and, having read the guidelines, that is why I posted the topic.  I'm not sure that EqualityComparer is the answer as one Equals method yielding different results from another Equals method is what I'm trying to avoid. I'll have to give it more thought.

Comment: FWIW - the use case for identity equality is common in service-oriented applications where an object is materialized from a service request and needs to be compared to an existing domain object. It is highly likely that the two objects will have different values for one or more properties but still represent the same entity.

Comment: I'll clarify my first comment a bit.  I develop frameworks and tools that other developers consume. Knowing my target audience, usage needs to be clear and consistent or acceptance drops quickly.

Comment: Just updated my original post to reflect my thoughts on how to potentially solve this within a domain where identity equality is a common occurance. Basically, I'd implement a new method on my base identity class - this keeps the logic local, seperate and only available where it actually makes sense without causing confusion re: Equals / == / IdentityEquals

Comment: I see.  I seem to recall seeing a blog post that mentioned a similar approach with an "IsSameXYZ()" method (where XYZ is the entity name).